# lm formula with variable names in it

Tags: r, formula, lm

I want to write a function that would take a `lm` model, try to add some feature and test its statistical significance. I've give it a go with the code as follows:

```
library(rlang)
library(tidyverse)
dataset <- data.frame(y = rnorm(100, 2, 3),
                      x1 = rnorm(100, 0, 4),
                      x2 = rnorm(100, 2, 1),
                      x3 = rnorm(100, 9, 1))

model1 <- lm(y ~ ., data = dataset)

dataset2 <- dataset %>% 
  mutate(x10 = rnorm(100, 20, 9),
         x11 = rnorm(100, 3, 3))

test_var <- function(data, var, model){
  y_name <- names(model$model)[1]

  dataset_new <- data %>% 
    select_at(vars(y_name,
                   str_remove_all(labels(model), '`'),
                   var))

  model_new <- lm(y_name ~ ., data = dataset_new)  
  return(summary(model_new))
}
```

As you can notice, to create a new model from available dataset I need to specify which variable should be dependent variable. However, I don't know this name directly, I just need to pull it out from the original model. So I did it in a function above, but it results in an error:

> Error in model.frame.default(formula = y_name ~ ., data = dataset_new,  : 
>     variable lengths differ (found for 'y')

Correct me if I'm wrong but I believe this is due to `y_name` being a string, not a symbol. So I have tried the following editions:

```
test_var <- function(data, var, model){
  y_name <- sym(names(model$model)[1])

  dataset_new <- data %>% 
    select_at(vars(!!y_name,
                   str_remove_all(labels(model), '`'),
                   var))

  model_new <- lm(eval(y_name) ~ ., data = dataset_new)  
  return(summary(model_new))
}
```

Although it seems to work, the resulting model is a perfect fit, as `y` is taken not only as dependent variable, but also as one of the features. Specifying formula with `eval(y_name) ~ . - eval(y_name)` doesn't help here. So my question is: how should I pass the dependent variable name to `lm` formula to build a correct model?

Comment: `y_name <- "Sepal.Length";
lm(formula=paste0(y_name, "~ ."), data=iris[-5])`

Comment: Do not delete your question when you get your answer. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/378440/caveat-emptor-making-students-aware-they-cannot-delete-their-homework-questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `dataset_new` contains the dependent variable in the first column, you may in fact use simply

```
lm(dataset_new)
```